# Ruby Time Period Class

Tags: ruby, time, sinatra

Does Ruby have a class that represents some period of time?

IE, 1 hour, 2 minutes, 3 seconds.

I realize there is the time class, but the constructor takes a year, month, and day. None of those are relevant to the abstraction that I'm trying to create.

Note: Working with Sinatra.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might wish to look into the `ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions::Numeric::Time` module of Ruby on Rails. It allows you to do neat things like

```
1.hour
=> 3600 seconds
1.day.ago
=> Mon, 19 Sep 2011 23:41:22 UTC +00:00
```

It greatly utilizes the Rails class [ActiveSupport::Duration](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html).

Comment: The mandatory link to the code: [Numeric time extensions](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/time.rb), and [ActiveSupport::Duration](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/duration.rb)

Answer (score 0):

Rails may have what you're looking for. Check out it's extensions to the `Numeric` class in the `activesupport` gem.

Comment: Even if you are, nothing to stop you checking out the source and implementing something similar!

Comment: You can require just the `activesupport` gem without the rest of Rails. I've done this with Sinatra apps when needed.